# TableView Reusabilty using segmented control

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view/Window which has a 2 segmented button on the top and a view below it.

When I click on the first button, the tableview with some data gets loaded on the view below. Now I want to use the the same table when I click on the 2nd button, but I want to add a few more section/rows.

The problem is when I click the first button the tableview gets loaded and the number of rows/sections method gets called. But when I click on the second button, those methods aren't called because they are called just once whenever a table is loaded.

So basically I get the same number of rows. I can do this with two different tableviews but I would like to use just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods will be called again if you reload the table data.  You can do this using this command:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: thnks a lot the problem was solved :) 
but ther's another problem when i press the second segmented button the table get updated but i cant press the first button again :((((

Comment: @Nitesh I'm glad to hear the first problem was taken care of.  For your second issue, please post another question and include some of the relevant code. I'm sure we can figure it out :)